Convert Geometry to 4326 in NetTopologySuite
I have a GeoJson file whose geometries are in 3857.
I want to read it using C# and insert its rows in a postgres table and I want the geometries there to be in 4326.
Also, I have some other files in other SRIDs like 7991.
How can I convert all geometries to 4326?
Geometry ConverteTo4326(Geometry geometry, string sourceSrid)
{
   // What to do here?
}


Does this solve your issue: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165022/transforming-point-using-nettopologysuite?

technically if it is in 3857 what you have is just JSON not GeoJSON

First off you need to get the well-known-text-representation for your epsg-codes. This is
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]

for EPSG:3857 and
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]

for EPSG:4326 (just look at https://epsg.io).
Now you can easily do the transformation:
CoordinateSystemFactory csFact = new CoordinateSystemFactory();
CoordinateTransformationFactory ctFact = new CoordinateTransformationFactory();

ICoordinateSystem epsg3857 = csFact.CreateFromWkt(epsg3857String);
IProjectedCoordinateSystem epsg4326 = csFact.CreateFromWkt(epsg4326String);
ICoordinateTransformation trans = ctFact.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(epsg3857, epsg4326);

var result = trans.MathTransform.TransformList(myCoordinates);

As web-mercator and 4326 are pretty common spatial references anyway, they are typically implemeneted in most GIS-related libs, so in NTS as well. So instead of using the projections-strings you can just use this:
var epsg3857 = ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.ProjectedCoordinateSystem.WebMercator;
var epsg4326 = ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84;


I have a point (-8890716.8205, 5491426.8879) in the EPSG:3857 coordinate system. When I transform it using the "ProjectedCoordinateSystem.WebMercator and GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84", it correctly generates the point (-79.86666806633664, 44.167673970340864). However, when I apply the transformation method from your first answer, it returns the point (-79.86666806633664, 44.359929900330826), which is not correct. Could you please help me understand why there is a discrepancy?
